# getting the autoincremnt value after inserting record using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

I'm developing a project using VB.NET connected to SQL Server database

and in this project i need to get the value of column called "ID" after inserting a record to
the database immediately.

thanx.

Comment: How are you persisting your information to your database. Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: What are you using as your DAL? ADO/LINQ/etc.

Answer (score 7):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (
     ID int IDENTITY
    ,[NAME] varchar(50)
    );
go

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable ([Name])
SELECT 'Joe' UNION
SELECT 'Jim' UNION
SELECT 'JIll'
;

SELECT  ident_current('dbo.SomeTable') AS [LastID_1]
        ,@@IDENTITY AS [LastID_2]
        ,scope_identity() AS [LastID_3]
;
```

USES:

- `ident_current ('TableName')` for a specific table, not limited by scope and session
- `@@IDENTITY`  last ID in current session
- `scope_identity()` last ID in current session, current scope

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT
    INTO [News]
    (
        LanguageID,
        Title,
        Short,
        [Full],
        Published,
        AllowComments,
        CreatedOn
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @LanguageID,
        @Title,
        @Short,
        @Full,
        @Published,
        @AllowComments,
        @CreatedOn
    )

    set @NewsID=@@identity
```

Comment: You should use scope_identity() instead of @@identity. If there are any triggers fired on the insert, @@identity won't hold the value you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT, and @@IDENTITY are similar functions because they return values that are inserted into identity columns.

Answer (score 0):

### TABLE

```
EMPID ( AUTOINCREAMENT)
NAME VARCHAR(50)

INSERT INTO TABLE ( NAME) VALUES ('RAMKUMAR')
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

use `@@identity`
returns the autoincreament value

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp table variable and create a column called StuId.

```
--Student table creation
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StuTable](
    [StuId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StuName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL
)

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(StuId INT)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StuTable]([StuName]
                            ,[DOB])
OUTPUT inserted.StuId INTO @TempTable
VALUES ('Peter', '1979-01-01')

SELECT StuId FROM @TempTable --Get the auto increment Id
```